# jQuery for animating border radius

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I have a problem animating `border-top-left-radius` style. I use this style by entering two length values separately.

```
border-top-left-radius: 15px 25px;
```

I would like to increase these two length values separately via `jquery.animate()`.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: have you tried these as a string?

Comment: what do you mean by separately? One after the other or as if they were totally independent controlled by two things that didn't talk to each other?

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but no luck.

Comment: The problem is, I don't know a way to access those two properties separately. When you set borderTopLeftRadius, it sets both of them to one particular value. I need something like borderTopLeftRadiusUpperLength and borderTopLeftRadiusSideLength..

Comment: At the same time. I can use html5 transitions but I have 32 different values for a div, and I did not want to define 32 different class..

Comment: ah, i see the problem. it doesn't work just changing one element of  the string '15px 25px'

Comment: Yes. I want to animate from '15px 25px' to, let's say, '18px 30px'.

Comment: Since it doesn't animate you could write a fn borderTopLeftRadius(x,y) that gets the starting values from the element and incrementally makes changes using css() at the correct percentage of each difference until they reach their target together.

Comment: Do you need something different than this: http://jsfiddle.net/saidbakr/kVCju/

Comment: sємsєм, the problem is that jquery.animate cannot animate border-top-left-radius values separately.

Comment: popnoodles, thank you. I think I will write my own function as you suggest.

Comment: See the documentation for the jQuery step function, which might help you: http://api.jquery.com/animate/#step

Comment: This could be something jQuery might like to include. I couldn't write it as succinctly as they would want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

border-top-left-radius accepts just one value right? So you would animate it like:

```
$('.class').animate({borderTopLeftRadius: 20})
```

**EDIT**

---

Not sure if jQuery supporst this out of the box. Maybe you can implement the step callback like this:

```
$('#container').animate({
    borderTopLeftRadiusSideLength: 500,
    borderTopLeftRadiusUpperLength: 50
}, {
    duration: 5000,
    step: function (val, context) {
        $(this).data(context.prop, val);
        var side = $(this).data('borderTopLeftRadiusSideLength');
        var upper = $(this).data('borderTopLeftRadiusUpperLength');
        if (side && upper) {
            $(this).css('borderTopLeftRadius', side + 'px ' + upper + 'px');
        }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YWsQn/1/

Comment: no it accepts two, it can use the arc of an ellipsoid not just a perfect circle

Comment: This is what I suggested too. He's already on it. I'd like to see the result tho.

Comment: Thank you both. It seems there is no other way but to implement this in the step function. I calculated the step count by dividing duration to jQuery.fx.interval, and incremented style values accordingly.