# How to get a style property with multiple values in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, styles

I have this div:

```
#centerFrame { background-color:#888; height:100px; width:100px; }
<div id="centerFrame" style="border-top-left-radius: 25px 0px;"></div>
```

but when i try to get the value of border radius it always returns 0px, how can I get both values?

```
console.log($("#centerFrame").css("border-top-left-radius"));
>0px
```

Comment: @TinyHaitian false. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-top-left-radius

Comment: Doh... I saw that and tried to delete my comment after I saw your post.   LOL

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, http://jsfiddle.net/6XcBy/

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13551857/jquery-for-animating-border-radius. might help.

Comment: @undefined you have to check the console on your browser, or you can use alert instead of console.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the right answer would be one of these without leaving the jquery context since any of these get the computed style but the property value:

```
$("#centerFrame").prop("style")["border-top-left-radius"];
```

or

```
$("#centerFrame").get(0).style.borderTopLeftRadius;
```

Answer (score 2):

Plain JS seems to do the trick :

```
document.getElementById('centerFrame').style.borderTopLeftRadius;
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/uF6gG/1/)

Comment: You're right, this works properly, thank you. I think jquery is missing something.

Answer (score 1):

`0px` is not a meaningful value for the horizontal/vertical radius component, so the browser is interpreting the entire property differently. What exactly would a `0px` radius component look like, if not identical to an overall radius of `0px`?

Counter-example:

```
<div id="centerFrame" style="border-top-left-radius: 25px 5px;"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/cCYAe/

Comment: You are right so jquery is somehow getting that style straight from the browser? in some cases jquery should return the same value as javascript.